# Opening excel file with tkfiledialog

Tags: python, tkinter

I have few code to open file in excel spreadsheet

```
filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="C:/", title="select file",
                                          filetypes=(("excel files", "*.xls"), ("all files", "*.*")))

os.system(r"excel.exe" + filename)
```

when i select the file i want read i get the following error:

> excel.exeC:' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

I tried to open with notepad wiht the `os.system(r"notepad.exe" + filename)` but i want to open it in excel using the excel.
I welcome your suggestion to open it in excel file.

Comment: Shouldnt just opening the file, open up the file in the machines default program?

Comment: Also - Try replacing this with your os.system function: `subprocess.Popen(["excel.exe", fileName])`

Comment: @Goralight it tried the subprocess it doesn't open.

Comment: `os.system(r"excel.exe"+filename")` will result in something like `os.system(r"excel.exec:/some/file.xls")`, which is pretty much exactly what the error message is telling you.

Comment: How about starting by adding a space after 'excel.exe' in your `os.system(r"excel.exe" + filename)` call...  You need that to give the OS a chance of understanding what you're trying to ask it to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specifically refer to the excel `.exe` file, however, you would need to use the full location and this can be different from machine to machine depending on OS, whether they've done a custom install etc.

Instead, you can simply refer to the file itself and the OS should just launch the file in the computer's default program for the file type:

```
from tkinter import filedialog
import os

filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="C:/", title="select file")

os.system(filename)
```

---

Additionally, the reason why you're getting that error is that when you're calling `os.system(r"excel.exe" + filename)` you're calling `excel.exe[filename]` without a space character.

This means that if you were trying to open, say, `C:/excel.xls` then you'd be calling `excel.exeC:/excel.xls` which isn't a valid command.

Comment: Have tried this but the file excel file in my working directory in pycharm doesn't opens

Comment: C:/Users/boy/PycharmProjects/REAL' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: That's because you're calling ` 
C:/Users/boy/PycharmProjects/REAL` which appears to be a directory or command and not a `.xls` file. The example I gave above will work if you run it how it is.

Comment: i copied the file to my drive C: it doesn't even show to be opened

Comment: Have you copied and pasted my example into Python and run it? If so, do you get an error or not? If you do get an error, tell us what it is. I've just given you an answer that I have working on my system and I've told you that, so can you confirm whether it's working for you?